# Convert IP addresses range to CIDR format and vice versa

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip, cidr

I need to convert `IP` range to `CIDR` notation and vice versa.I solved that    issue by `IPNetwork` library by the following way :

Conversion from `CIDR` to range :

```
    var ip = IPNetwork.Parse("192.168.168.100/24");
    Console.WriteLine(ip.FirstUsable.ToString() + "/" + ip.LastUsable.ToString());
```

And convertion from range to `CIDR` :

```
    IPNetwork network = IPNetwork.Parse("192.168.168.0");
    IPNetwork network2 = IPNetwork.Parse("192.168.168.255"); 
    IPNetwork ipnetwork = IPNetwork.Supernet(network, network2);
    Console.WriteLine(ipnetwork.FirstUsable + "/" + ipnetwork.Cidr);
```

It seems it could work fine. But when i use custom tools they return a little bit different result.

For `192.168.168.100/24`

The `IPNetwork` lib returns
`192.168.168.1` - `192.168.168.254`

http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr returns 
`192.168.168.0` - `192.168.168.255`

http://ipconvertertools.com/cidr2ipranges returns
`192.168.168.1` - `192.168.168.254`

http://ip2cidr.com/bulk-ip-to-cidr-converter.php returns

```
192.168.168.1/32
192.168.168.2/31
192.168.168.4/30
192.168.168.8/29
192.168.168.16/28
```

when i try to convert
`192.168.168.1 - 192.168.168.254` to `CIDR`.
I'm really confused that different tools return different result.
Also, my goal is creating of white list for users and check their `IP`s when they come, so it is a very important issue.

Comment: Read http://serverfault.com/a/10989/100461, it explains it well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so can users have ips that ending with 0 or 255 ?

Comment: If you read the linked answer it says that ending in `0` is valid in some limited circumstances, and that `255` is the broadcast address (which no individual system may use). So yes both a valid *addresses* but not really in the range.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you a lot, but what could you say about http://ip2cidr.com/bulk-ip-to-cidr-converter.php results ?

Answer (score 2):

Given the CIDR notation of 192.168.168.100/24:

```
Network address is 192.168.168.0 
First usable address is 192.168.168.1
Last usable address is 192.168.168.254 
Broadcast address is 192.168.168.255 
Network mask is 255.255.255.0
```

There is no and cannot be no ambiguity.